# Contributor breakdown bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation, docs-contributors

In the [contributor breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/404) for Creating and Initializing Arrays, I'm listed as having become a contributor for the example on September 19<sup>th</sup>, although I only had 341 characters out of the needed 350. (and was in fact awarded the proper amount of reputation for it) Why?

Comment: Looks like you're getting both +1 and +5 for each upvote for a total of +6 for each upvote now.... Looks like this happens whenever you go from a minor to a major contributor.

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed.

Comment: I believe this was fixed at the same time as: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335625/1438

Comment: @JonEricson actually it looks like they're the same issue.