# Calculation of major/minor contributions is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-examples, docs-contributors

[image]

1. The example had 2 major contributors (one having contributed 308 and -20 chars, another 567 chars).
2. I edited the example and was transformed into a major contributor.
3. Wrong things happenned:

   1. A user with a single contribution of 200 chars became a major contributor (should have remained a minor contributor).
   2. I became a major contributor at the wrong date, on the date I added 335 chars (should have become after adding 39 chars just now).

Links:

- [Contributors breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/34)
- [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/20/extension-methods/34/explicitly-using-an-extension-method)
- [Current reputation rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

[image: Updated contributors]

The root cause was that there were a couple ways* an edit could get counted multiple times.  For example, user3185569's edit was getting counted 3 times; and your 335 character changes was getting counted twice.

There are some rep implications (and some other bug fixes queued for rep in general), so a recalc will be rolling through later today.

As an aside: negative character changes don't impact contributions (if you add a net of 350 characters in one change, and then remove a net of 100 in a second change you remain a major contributor).  Those changes are surfaced on that page because that decision may need to be revisited, and we wanted the data to be out there.

<sub>* If you're curious: a `UNION ALL` in some queries, and `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level.</sub>

Comment: `negative character changes don't impact contributions (if you add 350 characters, and then remove 100 you remain a major contributor)` - Are you sure? I'm not a contributor at all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/41) despite [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/1360) change

Comment: @Rob The logic is done per-change, a net negative (removing more characters than it adds) change does not affect contributor status.  I've edited to the answer to hopefully make that clearer.